# Any Computer Vision library that can detect and recognize my face?

Tags: open-source, library, computer-vision, facial-recognition

There are many Image recognition library that can detect alphabets,face or object like OpenCV, EmuguCV, SharpCV... but is there any library that can recognize my face?

It would recognize my face from an image or video and distinguish it from other people's face.

Preferably Free/Open Source library

Language: Preferably Java or C#, (trying to avoid C++, but if Java and C# is not available then C++)

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul  thanks for the edit.